# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django

Hi m new in django framework and I am trying to solve this problem from 2 day 
I am getting this error after python manage.py migrate command.
I cant understand what the problem is?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date=timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

error

```
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages   /django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 262, in _alter_field
self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 206, in _remake_table
self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/letsperf/.conda/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: social_blogpost.title
```

please help I am confused !!

Comment: The error is clearly straight to the point. You have defined `title` as unique and Django won't let you save same value twice for a unique field.

Comment: now what should i do now ?

Comment: What were you trying to do? If you don't want that `unique` constraint you can remove it

Comment: i want title should be unique no one can use it again , Is there any other method you know ?

Comment: You already have an object with the same title in the database. Delete it or edit it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields), this is a summary of what the problem is;

> Applying a “plain” migration that adds a unique non-nullable field to
>   a table with existing rows will raise an error because the value used
>   to populate existing rows is generated only once, thus breaking the
>   unique constraint.